# Where can i find "Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t find microsoft.sqlserver.batchparser.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981027/cant-find-microsoft-sqlserver-batchparser-dll)

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 installed.

I want to Include `Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll` as Assebly in C#. But I cant find that dll.

If i go to my GAC Folder the Assebly is there:

[image]

But the references dialog box in VS2008 won't show it to me.

Where can i find or how can i get that dll?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981027/cant-find-microsoft-sqlserver-batchparser-dll

Answer (score 4):

The BatchParser is part of SMO. As a simple rule you are never allowed to redistribute a DLL that you did not create yourself, unless explicitly allowed. Redistributable DLLs come in redistributable packages. For SQL Server the SMO redistributable packages come in form of 'feature packs'. For SQL Server 2008 the corresponding feature pack was announced [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2008/10/18/sql-server-feature-pack-released.aspx) but the links to the feature pack itself are broken. You can use the [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=16978). It contains the [SharedManagementObjects.msi](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188438&clcid=0x409) which you need to include and distribute with your application to install the required SMO objects on your target computer. Another alternative is to use [an open source SQL batch execution library](https://github.com/rusanu/DbUtilSqlCmd).

Comment: I installed the SMO. But still can't find or include BatchParser. Do i have something else to do?

Comment: Did you install it for the right architecture?

Comment: Yes i installed Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Shared Management Objects X64 Package. In my GAC Folder now Appears Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser for AMD64. But still cant find the dll and the  references dialog box in VS2008 won't show it.