# could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.batchparserclient'

Tags: c#, sql, deployment, assemblies

Good Evening, I have a C# Winforms app with its deployment, where i did it, it works, in others pc it doesn't. Did somebody have the same issue and how did you solve it?

When I run from other pc is presents the next error:

could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.batchparserclient'

See image above

http://i47.photobucket.com/albums/f195/warbandit69/error1_zps3353dcce.png

---- Update 02-09-2014 -----

I added SQL Shared Management Objets AND CLR Types 2012 and finally get rid from last error, now i am having a similar one

http://i47.photobucket.com/albums/f195/warbandit69/error2_zps2749c6ac.png

Comment: You need to install all libraries that used by your application directly or by libraries that it references to.

Comment: I already added them, still same error @T.S.

Comment: It is clearly environmental issue. We all had it once before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can i find "Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376764/where-can-i-find-microsoft-sqlserver-batchparser-dll)

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981027/cant-find-microsoft-sqlserver-batchparser-dll

Comment: @T.S. already did that, still having this error http://i47.photobucket.com/albums/f195/warbandit69/error2_zps2749c6ac.png

Comment: Finally made it work, installing sql server 2012 with advanced services with all features on, tested again and finally made it work fine @T.S.

Comment: Are you planning to install Sql Server on every client machine? :o)

Comment: @T.S. i hope not, so i am still thinking on a solution for this issue, and not have to do that

Comment: You need something like this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065. I am sure there is a package for that

Comment: @T.S. Tried that, same issue

Comment: Still without a solution

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, i fixed this by downloading SMO and CLR for SQL Server 2014 version x86 (from https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=42295).

I'm on a 64 bits system, first I tried with version x64. Like you my error change from `microsoft.sqlserver.batchparserclient` to `microsoft.sqlserver.batchparser`. But version x86 is fixed the Exception.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to run old project on new laptop and tried **solution A** that did not work. But i figured out that when I installed newest version of SSMS(managment studio) it updated references in the project to use new dll versions f.e
*Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll, 
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll* that need proper version of 'microsoft.sqlserver.batchparserclient'
 but **solution B** worked out.

**Solution A**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43339

Download Summary:
 1. ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi
 2. ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35832.sql-server-troubleshooting-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-batchparser.aspx

**Solution B**

Remove all references to *Microsoft.SqlServer.SOMETHING*
and replace them with the version you have registered in GAC.

F.e I had references to version 14.x dlls in my project but i had
older versions registered in GAC (C:\Windows\assembly) version 11 and 12, even though i have installed proper files from solution A (newer versions, x86, x64 you name it)

I have replaced the dlls in my project references
from **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies**
to **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies**

It is not the neatest solution for your project references but i needed it quickly to work and it did.