# FileNotFoundException in c# connected with some dll

Tags: c#, sql

This is my updated question..

When I try to execute some sql file in a database using c#, I am getting the error as shown below:

[image]

My c# code is like:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "master" && comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "master.sql")
{
    oConnection.Open();
    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(oConnection));
    if (MessageBox.Show("Execute " + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + " in the database " + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " ?", "Execute?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        var output = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(@"D:\Testpgm\master.sql");
        if (!output.Equals(0))
        {
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + " executed successfully in " + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " database");
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Script Execution Failed,"+exc);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Execution cancelled by the user");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Either the database or the sql script file selected is wrong!!");
    }
```

Can anyone point out why this happens? I have tried almost all the things I found while googling, but unlucky to get what I expected..

I have also tried like adding binding redirect to my app.config since I could find "microsoft.sqlserver.batchparser.dll" version as 10.0.0.0 inside c:\windows\assembly and my c# application looks for the version 9.0.242.0, which again doesnt seems to be working. The code i used is:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas=microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="microsoft.sqlserver.batchparser" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="9.0.242.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
  <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: looks like when of your references is missing (`Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser`)

Comment: Btw, your first `if` is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: @AviTurner: Checked that earlier also..Now,once again I checked..But that didnt worked for me..

Comment: @Trickery:Doesn't think so...If you were right then it should throw some syntax error, i guess..and also i couldn't find any mistake there.

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal Well, then you copied the code wrong. You have two `else` statements one after the other.

Comment: @Trickery:If I add else command also..I am recieving the same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I have found out a solution for that. Just made some change in my code like this:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "master" && comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "master.sql")
{
oConnection.Open();
***SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlCmd.CommandText = textentry;
SqlCmd.Connection = oConnection;
var output = SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();***
if (MessageBox.Show("Execute " + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + " in the database " + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " ?", "Execute?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
 if (!output.Equals(0))
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + " executed successfully in " + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " database");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Script Execution Failed,"+exc);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Execution cancelled by the user");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Either the database or the sql script file selected is wrong!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like when of your references is missing ('Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser') .
In order to validate this do as follows:

1. Open your solution explorer (Ctrl+w, s).
2. Expand your project.
3. Expand the references "folder"
4. locate the 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser' reference.

Is the 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser' reference highlighted with an exclamation point? thought so...
Highlight it and hit F4 for properties.

In the properties locate the path. I suspect it is either blank or the file is really not there (as the exception implies...)

[image]

Comment: When the exception is thrown, can you tell what action was taking place? take a look at the stack trace. It might be happening from another referenced project.

Comment: var output = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(@"D:\Testpgm\master.sql");
This is where the exception occurs..What is stack trace?

Comment: call stack. its a Debug window that helps monitor the stack (hit Ctrl D, C for opening it).

Comment: showing the key combination is bound to command call stack which is not currently available..I dont think it is available in VS2010

Comment: For VS2010, it's found at `Debug > Windows > Call Stack` in the toolbar

Comment: Hi @VysakhVenugopal, I forgot to say it's only available when you're already debugging

Comment: @Darkzaelus:Thanks Darkzaelus...I solved myself by changing my code to use ADO.Net components for executing the script. Anyway thanks..

Comment: Not a problem :) glad you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully run your code using the 10.* versions of the assemblies "Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo", "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc" and "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo". Try downloading the 2008 version of the SMO components, maybe it was a bug that they've now fixed.

Comment: Is MS SQL Server 2008 Management Objects and Microsoft SQL Server Management Objects Collection different? I have already installed MS SQL Server 2008 Management Objects..

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal I think you have to reinstall it. Please check my answer.

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal . Looking around, this seems right. take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981027/cant-find-microsoft-sqlserver-batchparser-dll) SO thread. this explains why it is not available as a reference (it is installed in the GAC). I suspect that if you already installed it, there might be a version difference.

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal Please verify the version.

Comment: @AviTurner: Yes..The version number of that dll in the assembly is 10.0.0.0. But my c# application looks for the version 9.0.242.0. But in my app.config I have added an entry to redirect it to new version,that also doesn't seems to be working..

Comment: @Ajay: Sorry..That also doesn't work for me..I am not getting why this happens eventhough I have given binding redirect in my app.config.

Answer (score 0):

Different versions of the .Net runtime? If your application uses .Net4, but the dll to be loaded was created with .Net2, you can add an entry into the configuration section:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"></startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for this dll and can't install it via the relevant MS SQL Server Feature Pack, the dll is located at:

`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser\`

and then in a subfolder for the version of SQL Server.  If you're running the process as 32-bit, it'll be in `GAC_32` instead.  Copy the file into your application's `bin` folder and things should work.