# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# 4.6.2 test project that is using a set of libs in a folder, it is a collection of old version 13.0.0.x libs which on our newly install laptops appear to be missing Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll.

Does any one know how to get this into the GAC?
Or
Where to find the DLL for download?

I have found ver 14.0.0.x and above on NuGet and tried using the 14.0.0.x unofficial NuGet packs but that is throwing up yet more errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find microsoft.sqlserver.batchparser.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981027/cant-find-microsoft-sqlserver-batchparser-dll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a similar problem recently, but our issue was SqlClrProvider missing, which when fix then threw up the error you are seeing. We fixed this by jumping 14.0.0.x and 15.0.0.x and going straight to the 16.0.x.x-preview NuGet which has been working well for us in both our new dev laptops with the latest SqlServer and our old CI server.

Required a couple of small code changes, but they were very minor. I think something around ServerConnection object constructor.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects

160.1911221.0-preview

Hope that helps.