Why would this PowerShell script work on some database servers but not others?
I have a PowerShell script Deploy.ps1 which I inherited from previous developers. It uses the SqlServer module to interact with a SQL Server instance. This script is working on two server instances in two environments, but failing on another three instances in other environments.
The failure is on the last line included here:
$serverName = <load from configuration file>
$folderName = <load from configuration file>
$catalogPwd = <load from configuration file>
$ssisCatalog = "myCatalogName"

Import-Module -Name SqlServer -MinimumVersion 22.0.0

$ISNamespace = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($ISNamespace)
$sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=$serverName;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $sqlConnectionString
$integrationServices = New-Object "$ISNamespace.IntegrationServices" $sqlConnection

$catalog = $integrationServices.Catalogs[$ssisCatalog]

if (!$catalog)
{
  $catalog = New-Object "$ISNamespace.Catalog" ($integrationServices, $ssisCatalog, $catalogPwd)
  $catalog.Create()
}

$folder = $catalog.Folders[$folderName]

if (!$folder)
{
  $folder = New-Object "$ISNamespace.CatalogFolder" ($catalog, $folderName, $folderName)            
  $folder.Create()
}

# Delete and recreate environments
foreach ($env in $folder.Environments) 
{
  Write-Host "Deleting environment '" $env.Name "' in folder '$folderName'."
  $folder.Environments.Remove($env)
}
$folder.Alter()

The error is the same in all environments where it fails:

Exception on line  98
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Alter" with "0" argument(s): "Operation 'Alter' on object 'CatalogFolder[@Name='myFolderName']' failed during execution." ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcCRUDOperationFailedException: Operation 'Alter' on object 'CatalogFolder[@Name='myFolderName']' failed during execution. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I expected the PowerShell script to run on all environments. I have verified that the same version of PowerShell is installed in each environment.
I've searched through Microsoft documentation and the PowerShell syntax appears to be correct - which follows, since the script works on some environments. I searched StackOverflow for similar questions.
What else should I investigate?

Given the versioned assembly error message... do you have Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Shared Management Objects installed on all five systems?

@AlwaysLearning I don't think Shared Management Objects are installed on any of these systems. We already had to convert this script from using C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll to using Import-Module -Name SqlServer because the DLL was not installed.

You're not just using the SqlServer PowerShell module, though, are you? You're pulling in GAC assemblies with [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices"). Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices depends on Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc which, itself, also depends on Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser for a lot of operations.

See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981027/cant-find-microsoft-sqlserver-batchparser-dll

I clarified in the question that the version of PowerShell is identical in each environment.
